# Google API didn't receive any reports

Tags: android, api, google-maps-api-3

I am using GCM service on my new Android app , I did my code well but when I am running the project on my mobile I had exception that the project stopped unexpectedly , but when I commented this lines of code

```
 GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
```

The error stopped but when I was running the project error occurred and when I checked my Google API to check if the error sent to my Google API but I didn't find any reports why???

GCMIntenetService class

```
package com.example.elarabygroup;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

public class GCMIntenetService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
    public static String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntenetService(String senderId) {
        super(senderId);
        Log.d("GCMIntentService", senderId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onError", arg1);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        Log.d("onRecoverableError", errorId);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    /*
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.d("onMessage", String.valueOf(arg1));
    }
    */
    protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        Log.d("GCM", "RECIEVED A MESSAGE");
        // Get the data from intent and send to notificaion bar
        generateNotification(arg0, arg1.getStringExtra("**notificaion**"));
    }

    private void generateNotification(Context arg0, String stringExtra) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onRegistered", arg1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.d("onUnregistered", arg1);
    }
}
```

manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.elarabygroup"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.elarabygroup.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.elarabygroup.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ElarabyGroup"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_elaraby_group" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.elarabygroup" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Activity

```
package com.example.elarabygroup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class ElarabyGroup extends Activity {
    private String TAG;
    private String SENDER_ID = "xxxxxxxx";
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_elaraby_group);

        GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
        GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
        if (regId.equals("")) {
            GCMRegistrar.register(this, "xxxxxxxx");
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "Already registered");
        }

        try {

            ConnectivityManager con = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            if (con.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
                    && con.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

                builder.setMessage("No Internet connection");
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();

            } else

            {

                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.loadUrl("http://m.elarabygroup.com");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage().toString());

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

            String url = "http://m.elarabygroup.com/";

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

        }

    }

}
/*
 * @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 * getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_elaraby_group, menu); return true;
 * } }
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If log is available We can find the problem, so try to get log by installing some application like aLogCat in your mobile.

if you can't get that, Refer this tutorial

http://androidv5.wordpress.com/2012/08/15/how-to-implement-google-cloud-messaging/